# nodejs - How to deal with an API which returns circular structure JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the Zoopla developer API to get some historical pricing data.

My http get method is as follows

```
http.get(url, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  res.send(data);
});
```

I get `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON` when trying to use the above method.

Any ideas how to around this problem?

Comment: I am getting the data from a third party API hence have no control over what format I am getting the data in.

Comment: you can't JSON native objects with methods like response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second argument of `http.get` is **not** a data object. It's a response object.

You should do something like this instead:

```
http.get(url, function(err, response) {
  if (err) console.log(err)

  var data = ''
  response.setEncoding('utf8')
  response.on('data', function(d) {
    data += d
  })
  response.on('end', function(d) {
    res.send(data)
  })
})
```

Comment: or simply `response.pipe(res)`

Comment: I assumed he wanted to do some pre-processing after he returns the data, since it rarely makes sense to return the data unmodified. In that case buffering is the most simple solution.

Comment: thanks, yes the problem was me confusing the parameters of http.get